# Beginners guide to ask question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have read the FAQ and "How to ask" guide. But even after following that sometimes the questions are straightly down voted, without anyone giving clear instructions of what was wrong.

Is there any way to add the "What's wrong" with every down vote? Or any way I can know what's wrong in the question?

Comment: Usually questions with at least one downvote have at least one comment - or a close vote. Not always, but usually. If there's a close vote, you can treat that as a replacement for a comment, in many cases.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Thank you sir. I expected to get a clear answer like your's one. But also I want StackExchange to facilitate users so that they get good idea about the mistake. Because a person like you would not be available always. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to add the "What's wrong" with every down vote?

It is [encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) but not [forced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87140/down-voters-should-be-forced-to-leave-a-comment).

> Any way I can know what's wrong in the question?

If you have reviewed your question in light of the help center and other recommended guides then I guess you can post links to a couple of your questions here on Meta Stack Overflow so the community maybe able to provide some feedback on how to further improve your questions.